# Loop through three specific Outlook folders

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have Excel VBA code that imports Outlook mail data from one folder into Excel.
I change this for three folders all at the same level (not subfolders).

Is there a way I can specify and run the code on all three folders at once?

```vb
Dim mailFolderItemsB As Object
objOwner.Resolve
If objOwner.Resolved Then
    Set mailFolderItemsB = objNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderInbox) _
      .Parent.folders("Folder A") 'change this to B and then C once code has run.
      '.Parent.folders("Folder B")
      '.Parent.folders("Folder C")
    Set mailFolderItems = mailFolderItemsB.Items
```

This might be a second question if so ignore and apologies.
Is it possible to track changes?
Users often open mail, change the subject header and then close. Thinking of a old.value event.

My code.

```vb
Sub GetEmail()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim results() As String
    
    ' call function
    results = ExportEmails(True)
    
    ' paste onto worksheet
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(UBound(results), UBound(results, 2))).Value = results
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description & " " & Err.Number, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Database Error"
End Sub


Function ExportEmails(Optional headerRow As Boolean = False) As String()
    Dim objOutlook As Object ' Outlook.Application
    Dim objNamespace As Object ' Outlook.Namespace
    Dim strFolderName As Object
    Dim objMailbox As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    'Dim mailFolderItems As Object ' Outlook.items
    Dim folderItem As Object
    Dim msg As Object ' Outlook.MailItem
    Dim tempString() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim numRows As Long
    Dim startRow As Long
    Dim jAttach As Long ' counter for attachments
    Dim debugMsg As Integer
    
    ' select output results worksheet and clear previous results
    Sheets("Outlook Results").Select
    Sheets("Outlook Results").Cells.ClearContents
    Range("A1").Select
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    Dim OutApp As outlook.Application
    Dim objOwner As outlook.Recipient
    
    Set OutApp = New outlook.Application
    Set objOwner = objNamespace.CreateRecipient("EmailAddess@CompanyName.com")
    
    Dim mailFolderItemsB As Object, f, mailFolderItems
    
    objOwner.Resolve
    If objOwner.Resolved Then
    
        For Each f In Array("Folder A", "Folder B", "Folder C")
            Set mailFolderItemsB = objNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderInbox) _
              .Parent.folders(f) 'change this to B and then C once code has run.
            Set mailFolderItems = mailFolderItemsB.Items
    
            ' if calling procedure wants header row
            If headerRow Then
                startRow = 1
            Else
                startRow = 0
            End If
    
            numRows = mailFolderItems.Count
    
            ReDim tempString(1 To (numRows + startRow), 1 To 100)
    
            ' loop through folder items
            For i = 1 To numRows
    
                Set folderItem = mailFolderItems.Item(i)
    
                If IsMail(folderItem) Then
                    Set msg = folderItem
                End If
                
                With msg
                    tempString(i + startRow, 1) = .subject
                    tempString(i + startRow, 2) = Replace(.body, vbLf, "")
                    tempString(i + startRow, 3) = .Categories
                    tempString(i + startRow, 4) = .cc
                    tempString(i + startRow, 5) = .entryid
                    tempString(i + startRow, 6) = .ConversationID ' .ConversationTopic 'conversationID  or conversationindex.propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E") '.ConversationIndex
                    tempString(i + startRow, 7) = .LastModificationTime 'sent
                    tempString(i + startRow, 8) = .ReceivedByName
                    tempString(i + startRow, 9) = .ReceivedOnBehalfOfName
                    tempString(i + startRow, 10) = .ReceivedTime
                    tempString(i + startRow, 11) = .SenderEmailAddress
                    tempString(i + startRow, 12) = .SenderName
                    tempString(i + startRow, 13) = .SentOn
                    tempString(i + startRow, 14) = .To
                    tempString(i + startRow, 15) = .propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001E")
                End With
                
                ' adding file attachment names where they exist
                If msg.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
                    For jAttach = 1 To msg.Attachments.Count
                        'get pdf and xlsx files
                        Dim sAttachment As String
                        sAttachment = msg.Attachments.Item(jAttach).DisplayName
                        If Right(sAttachment, 4) = ".pdf" Or Right(sAttachment, 5) = ".xlsx" Then
                            tempString(i + startRow, 21 + jAttach) = msg.Attachments.Item(jAttach).DisplayName
                        End If
                    Next jAttach
                End If
            
            Next i
    
            ' first row of array should be header values
            If headerRow Then
                tempString(1, 1) = "Subject"
                tempString(1, 2) = "Body"
                tempString(1, 3) = "Categories"
                tempString(1, 4) = "CC"
                tempString(1, 5) = "CreationTime"
                tempString(1, 6) = "ConversationID"
                tempString(1, 7) = "LastModificationTime"
                tempString(1, 8) = "ReceivedByName"
                tempString(1, 9) = "ReceivedOnBehalfOfName"
                tempString(1, 10) = "ReceivedTime"
                tempString(1, 11) = "SenderEmailAddress"
                tempString(1, 12) = "SenderName"
                tempString(1, 13) = "SentOn"
                tempString(1, 14) = "To"
                tempString(1, 15) = "ID"
                tempString(1, 16) = "Number of Attachments"
                tempString(1, 17) = "Attachment 1 Filename"
                tempString(1, 18) = "Attachment 2 Filename"
                tempString(1, 19) = "Attachment 3 Filename"
                tempString(1, 20) = "Attachment 4 Filename"
                tempString(1, 21) = "Attachment 5 Filename"
                tempString(1, 22) = "Attachment 6 Filename"
                tempString(1, 23) = "Attachment 7 Filename"
                tempString(1, 24) = "Attachment 8 Filename"
                tempString(1, 25) = "Attachment 9 Filename"
                tempString(1, 26) = "Attachment 10 Filename"
                tempString(1, 27) = "Attachment 11 Filename"
                tempString(1, 28) = "Attachment 12 Filename"
                tempString(1, 29) = "Attachment 13 Filename"
                tempString(1, 30) = "Attachment 14 Filename"
                tempString(1, 31) = "Attachment 15 Filename"
                tempString(1, 32) = "Attachment 16 Filename"
                tempString(1, 33) = "Attachment 17 Filename"
                tempString(1, 34) = "Attachment 18 Filename"
                tempString(1, 35) = "Attachment 19 Filename"
                tempString(1, 36) = "Attachment 20 Filename"
            End If
        Next f
    End If
    
    ExportEmails = tempString
    
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    Rows("1:1").Select
    
End Function
```

Comment: It's a little difficult to suggest the "best" approach here since you don't show anything beyond the selection of the folder?

Comment: You're overwriting tempString each time you process a new folder.  You should pass a folder object to `ExportEmails`, get back the array with the information and place that on the worksheet, then process the next folder, etc etc.

Comment: Thanks Tim, sorry for my lack of understanding but can you show me how to do this as i have gotten completely lost with it.

Comment: I already added a full working example to my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```vb
Dim mailFolderItemsB As Object, f, mailFolderItems 

'...
objOwner.Resolve
If objOwner.Resolved Then

    For Each f in Array("Folder A","Folder B","Folder C")
        Set mailFolderItemsB = objNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderInbox) _
                 .Parent.folders(f) 'change this to B and then C once code has run.
        Set mailFolderItems = mailFolderItemsB.Items

        'something happens here...

    Next f
End If
```

EDIT: you have one huge function which does too much.  Try this re-worked example

```vb
Sub ProcessEmails()

    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objOwner As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim objOutlook As Object ' Outlook.Application
    Dim objNamespace As Object ' Outlook.Namespace
    Dim strFolderName As Object
    Dim objMailbox As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object, data
    Dim wsResults As Worksheet
    Dim mailFolderInbox As Object, f, dataRow As Long
    
    ' select output results worksheet and clear previous results
    Set wsResults = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Outlook Results")
    wsResults.Cells.ClearContents
    
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    Set OutApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set objOwner = objNamespace.CreateRecipient("EmailAddess@CompanyName.com")
    
    objOwner.Resolve
    If objOwner.Resolved Then
    
        Set mailFolderInbox = objNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderInbox)
        dataRow = 1 'start putting data on this row
        For Each f In Array("Folder A", "Folder B", "Folder C")
            data = MailData(mailFolderInbox.Parent.Folders(f), True)
            If Not IsEmpty(data) Then
                wsResults.Cells(dataRow, 1).Resize(UBound(data, 1), UBound(data, 2)).Value = data
                dataRow = dataRow + UBound(data, 1) 'next data dump position
            End If
        Next f 'next folder
    End If
End Sub

'Given an Outlook folder object, return an array of data about the contained
'  mail items.  Optionally add a header row to the array.
Function MailData(objFolder As Object, Optional headerRow As Boolean = False)
    
    Dim colMail As New Collection, itm As Object, data(), dataRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim arrHdr, dn, attNum As Long
    
    'only want mail items, so collect them in a Collection
    For Each itm In objFolder.Items
        If TypeName(itm) = "MailItem" Then colMail.Add itm
    Next itm
    If colMail.Count = 0 Then
        MailData = Empty 'nothing to report
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    dataRow = IIf(headerRow, 2, 1) 'data "row" for mail#1
    ReDim data(1 To colMail.Count + (dataRow - 1), 1 To 36)
    
    If headerRow Then 'adding a header "row"?
        arrHdr = Array("Subject", "Body", "Categories", "CC", "EntryId", _
                   "ConversationID", "LastModificationTime", "ReceivedByName", _
                   "ReceivedOnBehalfOfName", "ReceivedTime", "SenderEmailAddress", _
                   "SenderName", "SentOn", "To", "ID", "Number of Attachments")
        For i = 0 To UBound(arrHdr)
            data(1, i + 1) = arrHdr(i)
        Next i
        For i = 1 To 20
            data(1, 16 + i) = "Attachment " & i & " Filename"
        Next i
    End If
    
    For Each itm In colMail 'process all the mailitems found
        With itm
            data(dataRow, 1) = .Subject
            data(dataRow, 2) = Replace(.body, vbLf, "")
            data(dataRow, 3) = .Categories
            data(dataRow, 4) = .cc
            data(dataRow, 5) = .entryid
            data(dataRow, 6) = .ConversationID ' .ConversationTopic 'conversationID  or conversationindex.propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E") '.ConversationIndex
            data(dataRow, 7) = .LastModificationTime 'sent
            data(dataRow, 8) = .ReceivedByName
            data(dataRow, 9) = .ReceivedOnBehalfOfName
            data(dataRow, 10) = .ReceivedTime
            data(dataRow, 11) = .SenderEmailAddress
            data(dataRow, 12) = .SenderName
            data(dataRow, 13) = .SentOn
            data(dataRow, 14) = .to
            data(dataRow, 15) = .propertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001E")
            data(dataRow, 16) = .attachments.Count
            attNum = 0
            For i = 1 To .attachments.Count
                dn = .attachments(i).DisplayName
                If dn Like "*.xlsx" Or dn Like "*.pdf" Then
                    attNum = attNum + 1
                    If attNum > 20 Then Exit For 'too many attachments...
                    data(dataRow, 16 + attNum) = dn
                End If
            Next i
            dataRow = dataRow + 1
        End With
    Next itm
    MailData = data
End Function
```

Comment: That is a bad habit to call heavy methods in the loop to get the same folder three times.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev - agreed it is not ideal.  It was a "minimum edit distance" suggestion...

Comment: I have updated my code so you can see my full vba code as I still cant get this to work and hoping you can suggest where i am going wrong as it seems to run everything and only show the last folders info. thanks for bearing with me

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to retrieve the shared default folder for the user - this is a common operation which should be repeated three times in a row:

```
Dim mailFolderItemsB As Object
objOwner.Resolve
If objOwner.Resolved Then
    Set mailSharedInboxFolder = objNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderInbox)
```

Then you can grab the parent folder for your three folders:

```
Set mailSharedParentInboxFolder = mailSharedInboxFolder.Parent
```

And finally you can get three folders:

```
Set mailFolderItemsA = mailSharedParentInboxFolder.folders("Folder A")
Set mailFolderItemsB = mailSharedParentInboxFolder.folders("Folder B")
Set mailFolderItemsC = mailSharedParentInboxFolder.folders("Folder C")
'
Set mailFolderItems = mailFolderItemsB.Items
```

I'd recommend avoiding multiple dots in the single line of code. So, you will be able to troubleshoot easily and optimize the overall performance.

---

For tracking item changes I'd suggest creating an inspector wrapper, see [Implement a wrapper for inspectors and track item-level events in each inspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-implement-a-wrapper-for-inspectors-and-track-item-level-events-in-each-inspector) for more information.

Comment: So I used the first part of code 3 times for each folder (Dim mailFolderItemsB As Object, Dim mailFolderItemsA As Object, Dim mailFolderItemsC As Object)  I then ran this but it only gives me folder B am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try to iterate over all subfolders and see what folders are available there.

Comment: These are not subfolders, they are all separate folders, does this make a difference

Comment: Are they located at the same level in the folders tree? If so, you can use the `mailSharedParentInboxFolder.Folders` collection to iterate over all subfolders.

Comment: They are all at the same level example is 10 emails in folder A 10 emails  in folder B and 5 emails in folder C. there are no subfolders, just 3 folders at the same level. hope that makes sense?